# Laravel get data from all items from paginate

Tags: php, laravel

I have a paginate:

```
$posts = $posts->paginate(5);
```

I have a relation:

```
public function category() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

I need get all count category of posts. But How, if on page I have only 5 posts? When I do on blade:

```
$posts->pluck('category')->count();
```

I get only count for 1 page posts. How I can get count for all pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `$posts->withCount('category')->paginate(5);`

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$posts = $posts->withCount('category')->paginate(5);

foreach($posts as $post){
    $categoryCountForCurrentPost = $post->category_count;
}
```

Comment: I need do: `$posts->pluck('category_count')->count();` ?

Comment: Update my answer with example, please check